# Is there a R function for reversing ad-stocked values, or converting ad-stock transformed values to its pre-transformed state?

Tags: r, time-series

I have a vector of numeric values (a time series) where I know that an ad-stock carry-over transformation of 20% is applied to it. For instance,

- X1, X2, X3, … Xn (Pre-transformed time series)
- P1, P2, P3, … Pn (Ad-stock transformed time series),

where...

- P1 = X1
- P2 = P1 * 0.2 + X2
- P3 = P2 * 0.2 + X3
- PN = P(n-1) * 0.2 + Xn [the subscripts are a bit off, but hope it's obvious here]

The original adstock effect is applied using a function similar to the below:

```
    ## Function for calculating adstock
    #'
    #' @param x Numeric vector to be passed through. 
    #' @param rate Decay rate to be applied to `x`
    #' @export
    adstock <- function(x, rate = 0){
      x %>%
        stats::filter(filter = rate, method = "recursive") %>%
        as.numeric() %>% return()
    }
```

My question is. Assuming I only have the P-series above (i.e. the time series where ad-stock has ALREADY been applied), is there a R function that lets me get back to the X-series (pre-transformed time series)?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Use the same function on the transformed series. Just make the rate negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a simple algebraic problem.

The P sequence is defined by the recurrence relation

[image]

Solving for X then gives the following relation

[image]

So the value of *X* at point *i* depends only on the current and previous value of *P*.

This can be implemented using e.g. `dplyr::lag`

```
x <- p - 0.2 * dplyr::lag(p)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well. I've wrapped this in a function:
```
reverse_adstock <- function(x, rate = 0){
  y <- x - rate * dplyr::lag(x)
  y[[1]] <- x[[1]] # replace first value
  return(y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Maurits' answer, this ended up working for me. What I've simply done is to wrap the solution in a function. The first value needs to be replaced otherwise NA is returned:

```
reverse_adstock <- function(x, rate = 0.2){
  y <- x - rate * dplyr::lag(x)
  y[[1]] <- x[[1]] # replace first value
  return(y)
}
```